# Is it necessary to use @UserName in comments when only 2 users are involved?

Tags: discussion, comments

I will see a comments section like so:

@Bob Please post the getX() method - Sue  1 hour ago
@Sue Ok, just did that - Bob  55 mins ago
@Bob Also the getY() method - Sue  52 mins ago
@Sue Ok, it's there now, too  - Bob  43 mins ago
@Bob It looks like there is a problem in getY(), try using an int.  - Sue 40 mins ago
@Sue That seems to fix it, thanks.  - Bob 35 mins ago

In the case here where there is only 2 people involved, it is necessary (or beneficial) to use the @Bob and @Sue?

Comment: Why is Sue providing an answer in comments? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one of those users is the author of the post being commented on, then no, neither are necessary.  The post author is notified of all comments on their post, even if not replying to them, so if, say, Sue is the post author, none of Bob's comments *need* to reply to Sue.

Additionally, if there is only one user besides the post author who has commented on a post, then posts by the post author will notify that user, even if there is no @ reply.

As to whether or not it's beneficial, that's purely a matter of opinion.  Personally I find it quite useful, both because sometimes a 3rd party comments while writing a comment, but also because it simply removes all ambiguity that a comment is in fact replying to a specific person, but you're free to elide them when you know the intended recipient will be notified, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

### No it is not required.

The system will automatically ping the other person.

Once a third unknown gets involved then it pings the last commenter (I believe)

Comment: Ooh, what if a third person got involved and then deleted their comment?  Then the comment replies are needed for notifications?

Comment: Haha honestly I do not know ;-)

Comment: Using @Bob will cause Bob to be pinged, regardless of comment order?

Comment: This is only true if one of the two users in the example is the post author.  If they're not, then neither of them will get notifications.

Comment: Yep. That is the idea @AlLelopath